# REST API: Retrieve Keyword, Short Codes, and Long Codes

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, fuel, mobileconnect

Can we retrieve an account's SMS keywords, short codes and long codes in the REST API? I only see creating a keyword.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this about force.com or marketing cloud/fuel ?

Comment: Hi @SamuelDeRycke, it's about Marketing Cloud/Fuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SalesForce support has confirmed this is currently not possible with the API. Closing this one.